# Getting the cumulative distribution function for $\sqrt{X}$ from the cumulative distribution function for $X$

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I've a data set $X$ which consists of randomly generated numbers.

My aim is to plot the cumulative distribution function for square root of $X$ without generating data set for square root of $X$. I'm using Mathematica tool.

I'm confused and could not think of a solution.

Can somebody let me know how to take the approach here ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but maybe this is what you are after:

$$F_{X^2}(x)=\mathbb P(X^2\leq x)=\mathbb P(-\sqrt x\leq X\leq \sqrt x)=F(\sqrt x)-F_{-}(-\sqrt x)$$

This for $x\geq0$. It is evident that $F_{X^2}(x)=0$ if $x<0$.

Here $F_{-}(x)$ stands for $\lim_{y\rightarrow x-}F(y)=\mathbb P(X<x)$. If $F$ is continuous then $F_{-}=F$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$ cdf_{\sqrt X}(x) =  P(\sqrt X \le x) = P(X \le x^2) = cdf_X(x^2)
$$